# SQL Syntax Error after updating to WordPress 4.8.2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been using a hook in the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (load_field) which loads objects from a table in my database to an ACF select field. The table ('wp_new_royalsliders') is created by the RoyalSlider image slider plugin so i use the hook to populate a select field with the slider names.

This function has worked fine for a long time but recently stopped working - I think after updating core to 4.8.2:

```
    add_filter('acf/load_field/name=media_gallery_slider', 'my_acf_royalslider_choices');

    function my_acf_royalslider_choices($field){

      $field['choices'] = array();

      global $wpdb;

      $query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM %1$s ORDER BY ID ASC', 'wp_new_royalsliders');
      $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

      if(!empty($results)) :

      foreach($results as $result) :

          $value = $result->id;
          $label = $result->name;

          $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;

      endforeach;
      endif;
      return $field;

    }
```

When I turn debugging on I get an error:

WordPress database error: `[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%1$s ORDER BY ID ASC' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM %1$s ORDER BY ID ASC`

Comment: `%1$s` looks like a custom prepare syntax.. MySQL doesn't allow prepare query with a variable table name...looking to the error the custom prepare syntax isn't being replaced annymore..

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question* ? WordPress is updated to a version that includes a fix for a SQL Injection security vulnerability; the code is exhibiting different behavior with the new version, and ... your question is ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass in a hardcoded string value, you don't need placeholders, you can just use

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_new_royalsliders ORDER BY ID ASC');
```

If you want to get fancy and portable, you might opt for

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'new_royalsliders ORDER BY ID ASC');
```

So it would work on other prefixes, too, but that might not be necessary if this is a very custom thing that's not going to make it into any other site.

It appears that others have noted the removal of that possibility too, see [this request](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41925).

Update: as $wpdb->prepare() expects a second parameter (since its job is to escape variable inputs for use in SQL), it might complain. Solution: get rid of it and give your SQL directly to get_results:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'new_royalsliders ORDER BY ID ASC');
```

Comment: Hi Janh, your solution this solves one issue but creates another :) The select options now appear but i get a warning: Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() ?

Comment: Ah, right. You can actually remove $wpdb->prepare() completely, because all it does is escape variables in SQL so you can safely execute that SQL. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you janh!